# Is a simple random+hmac session cookie breakable?

Tags: session-management, random, hmac

I make session cookies of form `session_id+'|'+hmac_sha256(session_id, static_secret)` where `session_id = random_string(16 bytes)` made with a PRNG (not a CSPRNG!) seeded on the server's timestamp at start-up.

The cookies have the `Secure` flag so transport security is left to TLS to solve.

The session id is authenticated statelessly (i.e. without the need for a session database) the same way it was created, i.e. with `hmac_sha256(session_id, static_secret)`.

Is this breakable? If so, how?

---

Notes from brynk's answer:

- A revocation list would have to be queried as a second authentication step to allow for killing sessions on stolen devices. This will make the session authentication stateful (though the list would likely be short).
- The secret has to have 256bit+ of entropy if using HMAC-SHA256. Your cat should be able to handle that in 2-3 walks over the keyboard.
- Using a PRNG for session id as opposed to say, an auto-incremented id does not make the cookie more secure. The reason I prefer it is because 1) it's stateless (don't have to keep a `next_id` file around), and 2) it hides the information of knowing how many sessions were generated before yours.

Comment: maybe you can find a way of determing server uptime?

Comment: Why not use a library/framework that implements this?

Comment: @brynk Thanks for the comment. I don't know how you could do that, but even if say you could find a way to determine the server uptime down to the millisecond, at best you'll be able to figure out the sequence of ids from the beginning up to any number, in which case the scheme becomes equivalent to `hmac_sha256(auto_increment_number, static_secret)`, which I think it's just as secure, except for the minor information leak of knowing how many sessions were generated before yours. Besides, you can always just hmac the seed with the same secret.

Comment: @multithr3at3d because if this is secure, then I don't have to use a library, and because the purpose of the question is to try to understand something and using a library would not help me with that (plus I'd need to understand how that library works as well, so I'd be in the same spot).

Comment: As described, I don't see how your scheme couldn't be replaced with `sessid = get_secure_random(32)`? Stateless implies the client is holding additional session metadata, or that this is the key to some stored state. Please feel free to edit your answer/ elaborate. From an *'is this breakable'* perspective: it apparently rests on the entropy introduced by `static_secret`. See: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/ and https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final

Comment: @brynk I elaborated a little on the stateless authentication part. So the idea is that you can validate the cookie without having to use a session database, it's not about the cookie holding additional data.

Comment: @brynk replacing it with `get_secure_random(32)` would require a CSPRNG and I don't have one readily available (one more dependency), while a PRNG is standard in any language, and secondly, I couldn't validate the cookie without a session database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you're placing a long-lived token on some client device, then authenticating that device periodically with this.

At the moment, your authentication is stateless and involves the client providing the long-lived token: `sid + HMAC( sid , static_secret )`. The output of RNG has no bearing on things, because `sid` must be shared in the clear for stateless authentication to occur.

The security of this basically relies on the ability for an adversary to find `static_secret` that would then allow them to solve `HMAC( sid , static_secret )`.

So, the value of `static_secret` must be high entropy [and 256-bit if your hash algorithm is SHA256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60037) *Eddie and poncho discussing HMAC key sizes, '18*.

**OBSERVATIONS BASED ON ASSUMPTIONS**

What happens when the client device fails or is lost? How does the owner recover the data held by the service? This implies some separate account mechanism. Is there some way you can revoke `sid`? What if the client device is stolen?

Could devices interact with the server to derive a `nonce`, that is then used to demonstrate they hold the long-lived token? This would allow them to authenticate without exposing the long-lived token.

You haven't mentioned what transport/ network protocol you're using, and whether the server provides any sort of 'response', or whether the client just sends some payload to server without the expectation of any response.

I still think your device needs to somehow expose time to the stateless auth as well, which implies your client(s) have a reasonably accurate clock, that is relatively in sync with the server.

*(A lot of this- where relevant- could be rolled into the authentication token. but it's all still a bit vague: happy to revisit this again if you edit your question to provide some more information.)*

Comment: sorry but I don't see the point in any of this complication that aws does. is there any _reason_ for any of that?

Comment: ...as for putting an expiration time in the cookie, sure, but in my case that would be something like 2 years, so it won't help much, and also that's orthogonal to the question of how secure the cookie itself is, which is what I'm interested in with my question.

Comment: You're correct it isn't specific, and detracts from the answer .. If you could please edit your question to provide more detail on your requirement for stateless authentication then I will edit this answer to make it a lot more specific to your use-case.

Comment: ps. I still stand by my original comment - the security in the system rests on the entropy in `static_secret`.  Your PRNG can't add more than `static_secret`, so I've not considered it. (If it does then you need to address this first.) Also, in response to my observation to place a time-limit on things, you mention an estimate of a two-year expiration validity period for the cookie, which has me hooked .. so, it would be good to hear more about that as well!

Comment: the only reason for using a random number for id instead of an auto-incremented id is simply to hide the information of knowing the sequence of past and future ids. if you don't care about that, you can assume it's an auto-incremented id, just to simplify the discussion.

Comment: great points btw, yes, there needs to be a revocation list (so a session database, which must be hit for every cookie, just not for forged cookies), so maybe the phrase "stateless auth" is not correct, because only the cookie is authenticated statelessly in order to prevent hitting the db for forged cookies, but the session itself  is authenticated statefully.

Comment: `static_secret` is banging on the keyboard for a full line of text, I think that should be entropy enough but good point, I'll put an assert(length of secret >= 32).

Comment: providing the cookie is sent only through https, what is the additional security provided by the short-lived-token-to-avoid-exposing-the-long-lived-token part? is there a practical scenario that this covers?

Comment: I edited the question to specify the transport (https only)

Comment: *(Forcing the use of TLSv1.2+ mitigates this somewhat, so comment is info only.)* The rationale for signing a `nonce` with the long-lived token, is so you don't put the token itself on the wire. Without server presenting a changing aspect (eg. time or `nonce`), any bearer of the token is "authenticated" (replay attack). Secondly, if the adversary knows how the token is derived they can take any `sid` and perform some parallel search for `static_secret` 'til they get an input that produces a match. (This is why I say that the security rests on the `static_secret`, which must be high-entropy.)

Answer (score 1):

Even when `static_secret` is completely unpredictable by an attacker (and not reused for authenticating other values than session IDs), your scheme also relies on the **uniqueness** of `session_id`.

Imagine a server that sometimes repeats the same `session_id`. In this case an attacker could log in repeatedly to obtain a large number of `session_id`'s, along with corresponding valid HMACs. Then, when another user logs in and gets assigned the same `session-id` as previously obtained by the attacker, their session can be hijacked.

A non-cryptographic PRNG does not guarantee collision-free outputs, but the likelihood of 16 bytes being repeated is probably very low for most implementations.

Most non-cryptographic RNGs have a very long period: a Mersenne Twiser, for example, will only start repeating itself after about 10^6000 draws. The largest weak point is probably the fact that the generator is seeded by a timestamp. Consider a case where the web server is replicated and two instances are started at the exact same time. Additionally, the generator may use a non-collision free hash function to turn the timestamp value into an RNG seed.

Comment: Not sure I get the server replication part. You mean two load-balancing servers that both generate sessions for the same app? In that case, wouldn't it be sufficient to add some static id of the server to the seed?

Comment: thanks for the info on Mersenne Twisters, I didn't know their collision rate.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want achieve is very similar to what [JWT](https://jwt.io/) does.

From https://jwt.io/:

> JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.

Your cookie form `session_id+'|'+hmac_sha256(session_id, static_secret)` is almost the same as JWT's shown in the image below. In your case, you might put session_id in the PAYLOAD part of JWT.

[image]

So I think your cookie form is as breakable as JWT.

However, there are some disadvantages using JWT for sessions:

[JSON Web Tokens (JWT) are Dangerous for User Sessions—Here’s a Solution | Redis](https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/)

There are some ways to tackle those issues as well:

[JSON Web Token for Java - OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html)

I don't really know how you are using the session_id so you should probably check out those links to avoid mistakes.